# find the area of the region lying inside the circle $r=6$ and inside the cardioid $r=4-3\sin \theta$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Well, I drew a graph to visualise it and I found the interceptions $\theta=\arcsin \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)$. From the graph, by symmetry, I found that the area of region from $\theta$ to $\pi/2$ and from $\pi/2$ to $\pi-\theta$.

So How would I apply the formula now?

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry:
\begin{align}
\text{Area }&=2\times\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\sin^{-1}(2/3)}6^2\;d\theta+2\times\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\sin^{-1}(2/3)}^{\pi/2}\left(4-3\sin\theta\right)^2\;d\theta
\end{align}
[image]

Comment: May I know how u determined these bounds?

Comment: @John Since both curves are symmetric with respect to $\theta =\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute the area integral
$$\int_A {1} dA$$
where $A$ is the intersection of the interior of the circle and the cardioid i.e.
\begin{align*}
A &= \{(x, y) : r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq 6\} \cap \{(x, y) : r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq 4 - 3 \sin \theta \}\\
&= \{(x, y) : r \leq \min(6, 4 - 3 \sin \theta) \}
\end{align*}
So let
$$f(\theta) = \min(6, 4 - 3 \sin \theta)$$
and you can rewrite
$$A = \{(x, y) : r \leq f(\theta)\}$$
and the problem is equivalent to computing area of the region bounded by the closed curve $r = f(\theta)$ and so is the same as computing
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} f(\theta)^2 d\theta$$
[See [this link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx) for details.]

Now you have to split the integration range to the region where $f$ takes value 6 and where $f$ take value $4 - 3 \sin \theta$. It is easily solved: for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$
$$6 \leq 4 - 3 \sin \theta \iff 2 \leq -3 \sin \theta \iff -\frac{2}{3} \geq \sin\theta \iff \theta \in [\theta_1, \theta_2]$$
where
$$\theta_1 = \pi - \arcsin\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right); \theta_2 = 2 \pi + \arcsin\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right); 0 < \theta_1 < \theta_2 < 2\pi.$$
This means
$$f(\theta) = \begin{cases}
6 &\text{if }\theta_1 \leq \theta \leq \theta_2\\
4 - 3 \sin \theta &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Going back to the integral
\begin{align*}
A &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} f(\theta)^2 d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\theta_1} \frac{1}{2} (4 - 3 \sin)^2 d\theta + \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{1}{2} 6^2 d\theta + \int_{\theta_2}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} (4 - 3 \sin)^2 d\theta
\end{align*}
(You should be able to complete the computation.)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this is not based on the idea of symmetry, rather, you splited the graph into three parts by two interceptions and then got the area for each part?

Comment: @John That is right.

Comment: Oh Oh I get it, thanks so much. I have not seen this kind of approach before.